# error in a spray project

Tags: eclipse-kepler, spray

I am a masters student, and as I am preparing my final project study which requires to have a graphical editor for a DSL named `"VERISENSOR"`, I need to work with `"SPRAY"`. 
while following the tutorial that I found on eclipse, I found a problem in the file ( .spray )
once I add a class in this file, the following errors are displayed:

```
org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.DynamicEObjectImpl cannot be cast 
to org.eclipselabs.spray.mm.spray.ShapeInSpray 
org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.DynamicEObjectImpl
```

Comment: Is this question about the Spray framework for the Scala programming language?

Comment: no, i mean spray for creating a graphical editor